# vue router.beforeEach doesn't work on safari

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to use 'router.beforeEach' for checking token.
chrome can enter in beforeEach, but safari couldn't.

is there anything I have to know before use 'beforeEach' in safari?
I'm so confused and this problem makes me crazy.

here is code. there are meta : {authRequired: true} every components except login component.

```
router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
console.log("I'm in!!!")
let token = VueCookies.get('jwtToken');
let isAuthenticated = token !== null;

if (to.matched.some(function(routerInfo) {
  return routerInfo.meta.authRequired;
})) {
  if(!isAuthenticated) {
    if(to.name != 'login') {
      next({name: 'login'});
    }
  }else {
    next();
  }
}else {
  next();
}
})
```

**Google Chorme**

[image]

**Safari** so---------clean....

[image]

can I use beforeEach in safari?

Comment: yes, it might be a log setting preventing you from seeing it.  Try to add a `debugger` statement, and check if it is hit.

Comment: @StevenSpungin Thank you for answering my question. actually it fixed when i cleared cache and refresh. I don't know why It fixed....but thank you for your answer :) I'll try it later when the bug occur